# Grub2 won't install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

So I tried to download and install Ubuntu 18.04 on my asus 2-in-1 Laptop (Asus t100tam) I got it to boot into Ubuntu after adding a bootia32.efi file to /efi/boot after flashing with rufus with gpt partitions.

I then went to install Ubuntu and selected something else and made a 4gb swap partition and an ext4 partition with what was left and told it to install the bootloader in the efi partition that already existed.

It then got all the way to grub2 and failed to install it and therefore my new Ubuntu system is useless is there anyway to reinstall grub2 manually WITHOUT WIFI (I have tried the bootable bootloader repair tool and it doesn't work).

I am NOT DUAL BOOTING.

Comment: Literally if u read like 4 or 5 words before that it says the Ubuntu installer failed to install grub2

Comment: in case you're installing it on box with uefi, then it might be required to make an emtpy efi partition, please look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/827491/is-separate-efi-boot-partition-required and related links

Comment: I'm installing it on an Asus 2-in-1 pc model: t100tam I first install I did I made sure to keep the efi partition as I know it is required and this is NOT the problem the problem is that GRUB2 won't install as I get an error when trying to install it when installing Ubuntu